# How to map a decal onto a glass mug

Tags: rendering, uv, transparency

Complete noob here. I just started with Andrew Price's donut tutorial for blender 2.8. It's overall very informative (I'll have to watch it a couple more times for it to set in) but I went a little further with my coffee mug and am trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I looked at a few different videos on transparency in blender, then uv unwrapping...and down the rabbit hole. I'm really struggling with the idea of multiple textures on one object. In the tutorial Andrew shows how to unwrap his mug. I was trying to make an existing mug (see photo). It has a decal. I finally was able to get there, sort of. But I have a load of questions that I can't seem to figure out. 
1. What is the best image format for blender to achieve easy transparency? I started with a tiff, but through some of the tutorials I ended up with a png. This took a few extra nodes to get to "transparent" even though the png has transparency already.
2.After applying the "condensation" in andrews tutorial there were two "unwrappings". When I tried to apply the decal, that made a 3rd. Where does blender keep previous unwrappings, and how does it know which you want when applying multiple materials on one object?
3.My rendering (see photo) shows all the textures, but even the transparent part of my decal is showing a weird refraction or shadow. You can see the border at the top and bottom where this decal was placed. I just want the opaque pieces to show on the decal, and I want the glass material behind. How do I do this? 
4.Even though my decal characters are very bright in the png, the rendering shows them very very dark. How do I get them to look like they are printed on the outside of the glass?
Sorry for the noob questions, but I am totally in the weeds here. Thanks for your help! 
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: For the decals specifically you may want to check [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGxMY2lMoLw) posted by CG Thoughts. For posts in general you really should focus on a single question.

Comment: Note taken about limiting to one question in the future. I guess when you're starting out you still have so many questions. Just as a follow up to your video. This is great for the decals that are shrink wrapped, but I was under the impression that wrapping around 360 degree objects like a cylinder would be different. I'll do some more experimenting with the CG thoughts method. Thanks.